# Elasticsearch Curator cronjob

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, elasticsearch-curator

I was going to make cronjob to do curator on elasticsearch

`0 17 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator_cli --host localhost delete indices --older-than 7 --time-unit days --timestring '\%Y.\%m.\%d' >> /var/log/curator.log 2>&1`

It give me error on log

> Error: No such command "delete"
>
> Error: no such option: --older-than

What command should replace delete and older than?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, then I found myself by googling.
I am simply using yml to do the task.

`0 17 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator /opt/action.yml >> /var/log/curator.log 2>&1`

Here is the action.yml:

```
client:
  hosts:
    - 127.0.0.1
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  certificate:
  client_cert:
  client_key:
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth:
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:
  logformat: default
  blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```